# "Invalid Resource" message while trying to create a storage account in Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create an Azure Storage account using the Azure Resource Manager Connector in Logic Apps. But I am getting an error with the following message:

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResource",
    "message": "The resource definition is invalid."
  }
}
```

The raw input shows the following path

"path": "/subscriptions/28xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3c1f3xxxxxx/resourcegroups/abcdefgRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts%2Fintestcustomerst1111",

I don't know if the special character () getting converted to %2F in the above url is the cause of the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met same problem if I do it like below screenshot:

[image]

To solve this problem, we need to add the parameter(s) into the action and do not leave them empty. Like below screenshot show:

[image]

If you click "**Add new parameter**" and can not see the `Location`, `kind`, `SKU Name`... fields and can just see `Raw inputs`. Then add `Raw inputs` and do it like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Hury Shen. This solved the issue for me.